# Android: Couldn't find GA library on maven

Tags: java, android, maven, google-analytics

I am trying to add a `library dependency` from my `Android Studio` for below:

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
```

However, I couldn't find the package.
I even searched for it on `search.maven.org` but couldn't find it.
However in the `google docs` it is mentioned `:developers.google.com/android/guides/setup` 
Can someone point the mistake I am doing?
Meanwhile I acheived my task using [this link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

Comment: you also need to install google play repository from android sdk manager to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the Google Play services APIs available to your app:

1. Open the build.gradle file inside your application module directory.
2. Add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of play-services.

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
   }
   ```

Be sure you update this version number each time Google Play services is updated.

3.Save the changes and click Sync Project with Gradle Files in the toolbar.

Comment: why it is not showing on maven? the first one is shown on maven but the second one not. Do you know the reason why?

Comment: please install or update Google play services & Google repositories from your SDK manager. I personally tested it, it works on my project.